# difference between Powermock and Powermockito

Tags: mockito, powermock, powermockito, mockstatic

Can anyone could elaborate about **PowerMock and PowerMockito**. 
     I didn't even get documentation for powermockito.
     Both used for mocking static and private methods in different way I guess. 
     what are the similarities and usages? which one is better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerMock + Mockito VS Mockito alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036450/powermock-mockito-vs-mockito-alone)

Comment: That is for how PowerMock is build on top of Mockito. I need about powermockito, This is also build on top of Mockito only. I asked diff about PowerMock and PowerMockito not for PowerMock and Mockito

Comment: PowerMock is a framework that extends other mock libraries such as EasyMock with more powerful capabilities. PowerMock uses a custom classloader and bytecode manipulation to enable mocking of static methods, constructors, final classes and methods, private methods, removal of static initializers and more. 

PowerMockito is a PowerMock’s extension API to support Mockito.

Comment: The PowerMock framework provides a class called PowerMockito used to create mock objects and initiates verification and expectation. The PowerMockito provides the functionality to work with the Java reflection API.

Answer (score -4):

The main aim of PowerMock is to extend the existing mocking frameworks APIs with some annotations and methods to provide extra features that make unit testing quite easy. The PowerMock framework uses a custom classloader and bytecode manipulation techniques to enable the mocking of static methods, final classes, final methods, private methods, constructor, and removal of static initializers.

The PowerMockito is a class provided by PowerMock Framework used to create mock objects and initiates verification and expectation. The PowerMockito provides the functionality to work with the Java reflection API.